# Admob banner Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли проверить открытый ли сейчас баннер ? Необходимо скрыть баннер когда заходим в настройки, и открыть когда выходим из настроек, но когда баннера нет, не загрузился допустим или еще грузится, и мы заходим в настройки то выбивает нет ссылки.. как это можно обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, логично предположить, что прежде, чем пытаться что либо сделать с баннером, нужно проверить не равен ли он null. Вы пользуетесь [плагином для Unity](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases)? Через его методы доступна проверка загружен ли сейчас банер.
Точнее сказать трудно, т.к. вы не приложили кода, при выполнении которого происходит ошибка (в тексте ошибки пишется строка, в которой она произошла).

Answer (score 1):

Уточнение к вышеприведенному совету *Через методы [плагина для Unity](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases) доступна проверка загружен ли сейчас банер.:*

Используйте события OnAdLoaded и OnAdFailedToLoad класса  GoogleMobileAds.Api.BannerView:

```
...
this.bannerView.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleAdLoaded;
this.bannerView.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleAdFailedToLoad;
...
public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
Debug.Log("HandleAdLoaded event received");
}

public void HandleAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs 
args)
{
 Debug.Log("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: " + 
 args.Message);
 }
```